# Adjusting cell padding in LibreOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice-draw

I'm fooling around with tables in LibreOffice Draw and can't for the life of me figure out how to reduce the cell padding in these tables. You can see a sample of my table:

[image]

The image is super tiny, but you can see how the words have a huge padding around them in each cell (I don't want that huge space around the sentences).

I tried `selecting the table` -> `right clicking` -> `Table...` -> `Borders`, but nothing seems to work.

How can I fix this?

Edit: This happens with smaller font, but I have a ton of stuff I need to squeeze on one page so I have no choice:(, unless there's a way to widen the page?

Comment: It might be an optical illusion because the image is so small, but it looks like you made the table with a bunch of equal-sized rows of a certain height.  The space above and below is what's left after adding your text.  What if you just shrink the row height?  In some cases, you have multiple lines on the right and a single line on the left.  If the row height is adjusting, that will be based on the cell with the most content.

Comment: thanks for the pointers! how would i go about reducing the row height? i'm not extremely savvy with this tool lol

however, i managed to get what i wanted doing a workaround. i just increased the page size (`Format`->`Page/Slide Properties...`->`Page`->`Width/Height`) by a ton and in turn increasing the size of the table so it's more readable at its native size:D

this'll do for now haha

thanks!

Comment: I just opened LO Draw for the first time and did a quick look around, so my "expertise" is mainly intuition.  I stumbled across a few things that I can relate, but you might have to hunt to find them or read the help.  A few thoughts: 1) There was an option to make the rows equal size vs. varied sizes (might have been at creation time).  That may affect your access to individual row adjustments.  2) Whatever the relative sizes of the rows, you can adjust them proportionally by changing the overall height of the table.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you select the table, you get handles on the outer edges to adjust.  Also from the top menu: Format--> Position and Size.  3) The Borders control you were playing with looks like it's just a minimum gap between the text and the grid.  You will get a bigger gap if there isn't enough text to fill the allocated cell space.  4) I just recently switched to LO and haven't had a need, yet, for tables, so I'm just guessing on this.  However, there might be a difference in creating the table in Draw vs. Writer.   (cont'd)

Comment: In the latter, you're generally fitting a table into a document, so there may be more automation or tools to optimize the table for its use of space.  In Draw, you're creating artwork, so the tools revolve around tweaking appearance.  Just something to explore.